# Fish shell: flip a boolean value

Tags: fish

Am I going crazy? I want to flip a boolean variable. I came up with this:

```
function toggle_light_colorscheme
  if eval $LIGHT_COLORSCHEME
    set -U LIGHT_COLORSCHEME false
  else
    set -U LIGHT_COLORSCHEME true
  end
end
```

Does fish even have booleans? I suspect not. But it has `false` and `true` commands, I can `man` them. Anyway, I might not need a boolean. All I want to do is to have a global variable which, when set, would mean that I'm using a light color scheme in fish and vim. If it's not set I'm using the dark one. There has to be a simpler way of doing this, I wanted something like:

```
set -U LIGHT_COLORSCHEME (not $LIGHT_COLORSCHEME)
```

Comment: If the end goal is just to determine if a dark or light color theme is wanted, I would suggest staying away from putting true/false or 0/1 or has value / undefined or similar in shell scripts, but put sth like `set -U COLORSCHEME "dark"` or `... "light"` and compare the strings inside it. Because that is the clearest, less error prone and what is happening internally in shell scripting languages (without super weird syntax with return values of the true/false binaries) anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does fish even have booleans?

No. In fact it doesn't really have types at all, like the POSIX shells that it is inspired by. Every variable is a list of strings.

> But it has false and true commands

Yes. These commands return 1 and 0, respectively. Any return status != 0 is taken to be an error code and therefore false, and 0 is true (in this respect it's the inverse of C).

> All I want to do is to have a global variable which, when set, would mean that I'm using a light color scheme in fish and vim. If it's not set I'm using the dark one.

Sure, that can be made to work. There's a few different ways to go about this. Either you use the fact that the variable *has* an element as signifying that it is true, or you use that it is e.g. 1.

The former would work like

```
# Check if variable is "true" by checking if it has an element
if set -q LIGHT_COLORSCHEME[1]
# ...
# Flip the variable
set -q LIGHT_COLORSCHEME[1]; and set -e LIGHT_COLORSCHEME[1]; or set LIGHT_COLORSCHEME 1
```

(of course you could also make a "flip" function - unfortunately "not" is a keyword that operates on command return statuses, not variable values)

The latter would look like

```
if test "$LIGHT_COLORSCHEME" = 1 # the "=" here tests string-equality, but that shouldn't matter.
# ...
# Flip the variable
test "$LIGHT_COLORSCHEME" = 1; and set LIGHT_COLORSCHEME 0; or set LIGHT_COLORSCHEME 1
```

> I came up with this:
>
> function toggle_light_colorscheme
>   if eval $LIGHT_COLORSCHEME

You have misunderstood what `eval` does. It runs its arguments *as code*. I.e. it'll try to execute the value of LIGHT_COLORSCHEME *as a command*. So if you have a command called "1" somewhere in $PATH, it'll run that!

To test conditions, use `test`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going with the latter example. Only difference is that I want the variable to persist, so it has to be universal.

Comment: One clever trick is to use `test` and its exit value:

`[ "$LIGHT_COLORSCHEME" -eq 1 ] ; set LIGHT_COLORSCHEME $status;`

The idea is that (bool == 1) is "true" (zero) when the boolean is 1, and false when it's 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Fish and I hit this problem pretty quickly.  After some trial and error I decided my favorite way of solving this is using `set -q` and `set -e`. In other words, true means the variable is defined, and false if it's not.  So you can capture your variable with a one liner like so:

```
if test $status -eq 0; set isSuccessful 1; end
```

Then later, you can do:

```
if set -q isSuccessful
  echo "Success!"
end
```

For your example above, you can toggle `LIGHT_COLORSCHEME` with:

```
if set -q LIGHT_COLORSCHEME
  set -e LIGHT_COLORSCHEME
else
  set LIGHT_COLORSCHEME 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

2.5 years later and I was searching for "flipping (pseudo-)boolean variable in fish" and landed here! StackOverflow is perhaps the biggest written history of all (dev) folks…

btw. I solved this with the help of builtin math function easily!!

assume the variable called `bool` has been set to either `0` or `1` (the way booleans actually get interpreted in any low level lang):

```
set bool (math abs\((math $bool - 1)\))
```

_skipping the parentheses correctly was actually the main challenge! fish's cmd substitution style with just parentheses is very handy but interferes with functions which need parameter inside `()`, maybe there's also better way…

Comment: You can do it a little cleaner with something like this: `function flip_bool -a bool; math "abs($bool-1)"; end`. Obviously, comments make me put this on one line instead of 3, but you get the idea. No reason to double call `math`.